# TypeError: Cannot read property 'root' of undefined react and material ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

im using:
"
@material-ui
/core": "^4.1.1",
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
im just trying to render a button and im getting the error in the title of this post

i tried installing npm peer dependencies

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Link from "@material-ui/core/Link";

class Welcome extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Welcome">
        <p>This is your public-facing component.</p>
        <Link
          component="button"
          variant="body2"
          onClick={() => {
            alert("I'm a button.");
          }}
        >
          Button Link
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Welcome;
```

I should see the link

Code calling the above component

```
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Welcome from './Welcome';
import Secured from './Secured';
import Logout from './Logout';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container">
          <ul>
            <li><Link to="/">public component</Link></li>
            <li><Link to="/secured">secured component</Link></li>
          </ul>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
          <Route path="/secured" component={Secured} />
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
export default App;

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Nothing in that code should cause that error, can you post the code calling this ?

Comment: I don't have any problem running your code after copy/paste in a sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/soanswer56709491-rjptj  Would you have more runnable code to try out? Possibly a full code on GitHub or a runnable CodeSandbox  sample would be helpful

Comment: ok i just added to above

Comment: Please show the code that is using `App` (probably index.js).

Comment: thi sis the link to my repo
https://github.com/aavram/PoliticianPollReact

Comment: i added index.js

Comment: Here's a CodeSandbox based on your repository: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/aavram/PoliticianPollReact. I don't see the error.

Comment: i just restarted my server and it works! thanks a lot!